# From where can I get this font for Android

Tags: android

I need to use the following font in my android app from where can I get it or what it's name?:

[image: Eclipse font]

It's used in eclipse xml layout string field.

Comment: find in the eclipse appearance for code font all the other thing and copy that font to asset folder and use in your application

Comment: I've looked there but didn't find it.

Comment: Flag: This question belongs on [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), Q&A for professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font is the italic version of Consolas.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac that font is Monaco. I am not sure what it is on Eclipse for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for at least understanding the question. It's not that hard.

Comment: Go to the preferences, go to General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > java then click the java editor text font. It will tell you.

Comment: Already did before asking the question didn't find there it show Consolas and its not this one.

Answer (score 0):

check this image for getting appearance of eclipse

appearance for font

[image]

edit the font

[image]